# How to fix: Vuequill rich editor Link tooltip moving out of the editor container

Tags: quill, rich-text-editor, vue-quill-editor

I'm using quill rich text editor, found the link tooltip will move out of the editor container. Anyone has found the issue and any idea how to fix?

The demo link:
https://quilljs.com/docs/themes/

First: select "google.com" to add a link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIeFM.png)

Second: move the scroll bar, the link tooltip moved out of the container:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egmuw.png)

I tried to fix this by hide the link tooltip when the scroll bar moving, or let the link tooltip not overflow out of the container. Not sure how to achieve this.